# Add differents meta tag every joomla article

Tags: facebook, joomla, meta-tags

I'd like to add facebook open graph  tags in my **joomla** website.
I edited index.php and add manually:

```
<head>
    <title>The Rock (1996)</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
                   a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
                   threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
                   weapons."/>

  </head>
```

In this way meta tags is applied to all my website pages.

**How can I add different meta tags for every joomla article?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of the Open Graph Plugins for Joomla standard content if you like.
Maybe like http://itprism.com/free-joomla-extensions/social-marketing-seo/open-graph-meta

Answer (score 5):

A basic method of stitching the meta tags is explained in [this article](http://forum.techbubble.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=3).

```
$opengraph    = '<meta property="og:title" content="'.$game->title.'"/>' ."\n";
$opengraph .= '<meta property="og:type" content="'."BLOG_replacewithyourtype".'"/>' ."\n";
$opengraph .= '<meta property="og:url"  content="'. $myabsoluteurl.'"/>' ."\n";
$opengraph .= '<meta property="og:image" content="'."http://YOURSITE.com/.../images/".$blog->imagename.'"/>' ."\n";
$opengraph .= '<meta property="og:site_name" content="'."YOUR SITE TITLE".'"/>' ."\n";
$opengraph .= '<meta property="fb:admins" content="'."YOUR FACE BOOK DEVELOPER CODE".'"/>' ."\n";
//add the tags to the head of the page;[/
$document->addCustomTag($opengraph);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add specific meta to each article via the navigation menu in the administratio0n back end.  Each parent and child has its own meta fields located via the dropdowns on the right hand side when viewing a particular navigation item.